# Why don't see chart of width 50px & height 25px

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I need many very small charts on one page, but if I set width 50px and height 25px I do not see chart. Also I will thanks of suggestions other libraries to create more than 200 charts on page without performance problem.

I tried set width and height via css on parent div.

https://codesandbox.io/s/m5pl96l8op

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chart from "react-chartist";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Chart
        className="chart"
        data={{
          series: [[1, 3, 2, 8, 4, 12, 27, 16]]
    }}
    type="Line"
    options={{
      fullWidth: true,
      width: "50px",
      height: "25px",
      showPoint: false,
      axisY: {
        showGrid: false,
        showLabel: false
      },
      axisX: {
        showGrid: false,
        showLabel: false
      }
    }}
  />
    </div>);
}
```

I expect very small chart, but I does not see any chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Chartist's docs](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#module-chartistline), you'll find all the options available and their default values.

Your issue here is that there are margins and paddings everywhere by default, which leaves very little space for your data. Here are the options you can use to remove any extra space:

https://codesandbox.io/s/4lxl0qvly9

```
function App() {
  // We'll use this multiple times, so declare it here
  const series = [1, 3, 2, 8, 4, 12, 27, 16];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Chart
        className="chart"
        data={{
          series: [series]
        }}
        type="Line"
        options={{
          fullWidth: true,
          width: "50px",
          height: "25px",
          low: Math.min(...series), // Remove space around min and max values
          high: Math.max(...series), // Remove space around min and max values
          chartPadding: {
            // Remove all padding
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0
          },
          showPoint: false,
          axisY: {
            offset: 0, // Remove any offset
            position: "start", // Remove any bottom margin
            showGrid: false,
            showLabel: false
          },
          axisX: {
            offset: 0, // Remove any offset
            position: "start", // Remove any left margin
            showGrid: false,
            showLabel: false
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```